# Calculating Odds of Getting a Sample w/ a Specific Standard Deviation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, z-score, odds

Trying to calculate the odds on something and was getting myself confused.  I'll try to summarize into a simple problem with made up numbers.

Say a cannon fires projectiles with a population mean of 100 m/s and a standard deviation of 10 m/s, represented by a normal distribution.

I wanted to calculate the odds of firing off 15 rounds in a row that would have a standard deviation between 0 m/s and 2 m/s.

I basically calculated two z-scores:

Z1 = (101-100)/10 and Z2 = (99-100)/10.

Then assumed the probability of getting one round within that range was (using table for standardized z-scores):

P = P(X < Z1) - P(X < Z2)

To fire 15 rounds within that range, then I said P_15 = P^15.

Although, I feel more like I am calculating the odds of my sample to have more more like 3+ sigma (of 2 m/s), since with 1-sigma all the rounds from the sample don't necessarily have to fall within the +/- 1 m/s range, just ~68% of them.  But, I really would like the sample to have a 1-sigma between 0m/s and 2 m/s.

Question: what is the correct way to formulate this problem and what are the details of the calculation?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question has no unique answer for the information given.  If you assume a specific distribution for the speeds, then the question can be answered, so please edit it to include that information.  [There exist analytic answers for some distributions, such as a Normal distribution. For it, a known multiple of the sample standard deviation has a chi distribution. Note that the chance that the sample SD is exactly $2$ will be zero: you need to ask for the chance that the SD lies within some given range, such as $0-2$. For a Normal distribution, that chance is one in 48 million.]

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was obvious it was a normal distribution.  Although I guess that brings up another question:  Is that assumption not as obvious as I thought?  Are there reasons to think cannon (or any type of gun) muzzle velocities would not be represented by a normal distribution around some mean velocity?  However, I guess for the sake of this problem, let's assume both the population and samples can be represented by normal distributions.

Comment: There's obvious reasons to think it *wouldn't* be normal -- muzzle velocity is necessarily non-negative, and presuming you'll only consider projectiles that exit the barrel, actually necessarily positive. As a result you'd tend to expect somewhat skewed distributions (one can at least consider a possibility of a cannonball exiting with a bit more than double the mean velocity but it's impossible to be that below the mean, since that would be negative). It might be reasonable in some situations to use a normal approximation, but it's by no means obvious that one should automatically do so.

Comment: Hello Glen_b, I have access to large databases of the particular "gun" in question.  I would have to say it is a near impossibility to ever see a muzzle velocity at double the mean for this particular "gun".  Physically, where is that energy going to come from?  All the prop charges are within 1% of each other in terms of weight, coming from a relatively consistent manufacturing process.  In addition, plots of the muzzle velocity sure look like a normal distribution, with a tight standard deviation around the mean that is fractions of the mean velocity.

Comment: Remember, the numbers I put in the OP above are "made up" and don't represent the actual "gun" in question.  I would say the problem might even get more pointed with match-grade rifle bullets.  You're just not going to see a bullet come out at double the muzzle velocity.  So, considering the type of performance I mention above, is there any reason to suspect something other than a normal distribution, supported with physical reasoning that justifies any (significant) departure from normality.  I'm not saying there isn't, just having a hard time imagining it.

Comment: @whuber, I believe you've answered my question in your comment.  Any chance of filling in the details in an "answer"?  I'm not able to make the jump to calculating out the one in 48 million myself, given the amount of information given.  Would be much appreciated ;-)

Comment: Ethan, concerning the distribution: Suppose, for the sake of imagining what might go on, that the *dimensions* of the explosive charge in the cannon have a joint Normal distribution.  That implies (from geometry alone) that the volume of the charge itself varies like the *cube* of a Normal distribution. Assuming muzzle speed is proportional to the mass of the charge and the mass if proportional to its volume, that would yield a positively skewed, non-Normal distribution of speeds.  Regardless, the answer might not depend too strongly on the shape of the distribution.

Comment: Thanks whuber, that's very interesting and something we hadn't thought of.  Again, the masses are so tightly grouped (and pass a MATLAB chi2gof test for normality) I think they are "normal enough" for normality to be a reasonable assumption.  Nonetheless, interesting point and I learned something new from it about distributions.  again, would love to see the details spelled out as to how you reached 1 in 48 million above  (wink, wink)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know for a normal distribution that $${ \left( n-1 \right) s^2 \over \sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1} $$

Equivalently (since a chi-squared distribution is a gamma distribution), we can say that  $${ \left( n-1 \right) s^2 \over \sigma^2} \sim \textrm{Gamma} \left( \frac{n-1}{2},2 \right) .$$

Now if $X \sim \textrm{Gamma} \left( \alpha, \beta \right) ,$ then $kX \sim \textrm{Gamma} \left( \alpha, k \beta \right) $

Therefore $$ s^2 \sim \textrm{Gamma} \left( \frac{n-1}{2},\frac{2 \sigma^2}{n-1} \right)$$

For the values you have of $n$ and $\sigma^2,$ that means $$s^2 \sim \textrm{Gamma} \left(7,\frac{100}{7} \right) $$

Now checking the CDF for this gamma random variable, $$P[s^2 < 4]=2.096444E-08,$$ which is about 1 in 47,699,809

Comment: Thanks for the reply soakley.  I'm a bit confused going from eq 1 to 2.  Is that a Chi^2 on the RHS of your first equation?  How does that jive with a gamma distribution in the second equation.  Also, can you provide a reference/link where I can see the justification (or even a derivation) for the first equation?  (Or, if you could provide any details, that would be great too).

Comment: That is a chi-squared distribution and a  $\chi^2_p$ distribution is a special case of the Gamma Distribution, where $\alpha = p/2$ and $\beta=2$, using the pdf characterization described in Casella and Berger, 2nd ed., 2002.

Comment: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/174 has a derivation of statement 1

Comment: Where does it help the OP understand how to get to a Gamma from a chi-squared distribution on that page, @MaxS.?

Comment: It doesn't. OP asked "Also, can you provide a reference/link where I can see the justification (or even a derivation) for the first equation?" @Analyst1

Comment: Got it.  I was looking in the reference for the Gamma link bud didn't see it. I see now that you were addressing a different question!  Thanks!

Comment: This was all very helpful and I've almost got all the pieces filled in that were missing for me.  I've replicated the above answer in MATLAB, but I'm still a bit stuck on understanding the parameters in the gamma dist. above.  alpha = (15-1)/2 = 7, where the 15 is my sample size, correct?  But, why the 100/7 for beta?  Looks like population mean divided by alpha, but why would that be?  I guess I was expecting beta = 2, based on Analysts1's comment.  Also, where does my population standard deviation of 10 come in?  This seems like it should be crucial to calculating the probability I'm after.

Comment: I've added in some more detail to address how the beta parameter is found.